# Passionate to dance vs passionate about dancing

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I was going through one of the famous dance celebrity's Instagram profile today and the Bio wrote

> "Passionate to dance"

I know, Passionate about dancing is correct, but is passionate to Dance also the correct usage ?

Answer (score 2):

## Passionate about something

We say you are **passionate about something**, not *passionate to something*.

> ✔️**Yes:** “I am passionate about dance.”
>
> -- [Deccan Herald](https://www.deccanherald.com/amp/content/193802/i-am-passionate-dance.html)
>
> ✔️**Yes:** “Casting NYC Dancers who are Passionate about Dance”
>
> -- [“Vitamin Enriched Films”](https://vitaminenrichedfilms.com/casting-nyc-dancers-who-are-passionate-about-dance-for-an-online-campaign-pays-5k/realpeoplecasting)
>
> ✔️**Yes:** My Passion for Dancing
>
> -- Marie Malone, [Awesome Sports Project](https://www.awesomesportsproject.com/features/2018/04/17/my-passion-for-dancing)

Answer (score 0):

The difference to me is that "passionate about dancing" can mean "I like dancing as art and when others do it", while "passionate to dance" is closer to "passionate dancer", that is "I really like to dance".

Compare that to "passionate about soccer" versus "passionate about playing soccer". In forst case it sounds like person is really into watching games on TV, but might play it as well.

Comment: I don’t think “Passionate to dance” is a valid phrase. Please provide some usage examples to improve this answer!